# Aplicação Intermitente

Tags: .net, iis

Tenho um sistema desenvolvido em .net framework 4.0 rodando no IIS 7.5. De vez em quando, o sistema dá um problema em que nenhum usuário consegue logar mais no mesmo, porém, nestes momentos, quando executo a aplicação pelo Visual Studio e aponto para esta base para tentar debugar o erro, o mesmo não acontece, consigo entrar normalmente.

Quando este tipo de problema acontece eu faço um recycle no pool da aplicação e o sistema volta ao normal.

[image: print do erro]

Como solucionar isto?

Comment: Só olhando o stacktrace fica meio difícil. Eu vi que no seu faz menção a `WeakReference`, pode estar envolvido com o problema. Mas não dá para saber sem você postar o fonte pertinente.

Comment: Um dos erros mais comuns entre programadores é o Null Reference ou Null Pointer. Tem algum lugar no seu código que está apontando para algo nulo. Coloque código na pergunta, fica mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Eu percebi uma outra coisa. Bom, o projeto utiliza uma classe estática para conexão com o banco de dados. Caso o problema aconteça, se eu reinicio esta conexão, mesmo não fazendo um recycle no pool, a aplicação volta ao normal.

Comment: Pela mensagem que você postou ae parece que você esqueceu de alocar algum objeto: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ...` essa é a causa do erro, pelo stack trace ae parece que o erro ocorre em `Models.Administracao.Perfil.Carregar`, da uma olhada na stack trace também!